# list in python, loop for, array

Tags: arrays, list, for-loop, python-2.7

as a green hand python programmer, I have a little problem, I'll appreciate if somebody can help!!

I have two lists

a list of random  repeated numbers(unknow size) like:

```
number = [44,198,57,48,658,24,7,44,44,44..]
```

for n in number
I want to give these numbers to a list of people in order, one number for one person. If a number repeat, the program will find out the person whom got this number when the first time it shows up.  It means I want to print a list like

```
people = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,1,1...]

print people
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the mapping from numbers to indexes in a `dict`, and update it as you go.

```
numbers = [44,198,57,48,658,24,7,44,44,44.]
index_mapping = {}
indexes = []
next_index = 1
for number in numbers:
    if number in index_mapping:
        # already seen
        indexes.append(index_mapping[number])
    else:
        # a new one
        indexes.append(next_index)
        index_mapping[number] = next_index
        next_index += 1

print indexes
```